# How to render selected values into a multi drop down box

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a multi select box and I want to be able to select the values in the multi box based on values coming from an array.  I am using vuejs.  Any ideas? The way that I've tried to solve it is obviously very wrong.  Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<div id="app">

<select class="multiselect"  v-model="mySelect" multiple  class="multi-size">
      <option>Access</option>
      <option>BA Briefings</option>
      <option>Change Management</option>
      <option>Clearance</option>
      <option>Communications</option>
      <option>CONUS</option>
      <option>Delay</option>
      <option>Disruption</option>
      <option>eQIP</option>
    <option>Field Ops</option>                                                                                                               
  </select>  


  <button @click="add">Add selection</button>
</div>


new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
     mySelect:'',
     selData: ["Access", "BA Briefings", "CONUS", "Delay"]
    }      
  },
  methods: {
    add: function(){
      this.selData.forEach(data=>{
        this.mySelect = data;
      })
    }
  }
})
```

Here's a [pen](https://codepen.io/isogunro/pen/ce57745480e9357e905297f8e993786e?editors=1010).

Comment: Check out the _"dynamic options"_ part here ~ https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to do two changes, as it is multiselect, have mySelect as array. Second, add the element to the array as you want multiple item selected at the same time based on your array.
Updated your code, hope this helps.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
     mySelect:[],
     selData: ["Access", "BA Briefings", "CONUS", "Delay"]
    }      
  },
  methods: {
    add: function(){
      this.selData.forEach(data=>{
        this.mySelect.push(data);
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
<select class="multiselect"  v-model="mySelect" multiple  class="multi-size">
      <option>Access</option>
      <option>BA Briefings</option>
      <option>Change Management</option>
      <option>Clearance</option>
      <option>Communications</option>
      <option>CONUS</option>
      <option>Delay</option>
      <option>Disruption</option>
      <option>eQIP</option>
    <option>Field Ops</option>
  </select>  
  <button @click="add">Add selection</button>
</div>
```

Comment: How would I do this on page load without a button?

Comment: Instead of having empty mySelect, set the data of mySelect with what you want and it will appear selected on page load.

Comment: I'm having a hard time setting the multi select box with the values from the array  https://codepen.io/isogunro/pen/ExxwPOY?editors=1011

Comment: My array name is 
dropDowns
 and the multi select box is the 'Company' column